# Create custom view to be used throughout Xamarin Forms App

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wish to create a custom view (a label and an entry in a vertical stack) which I have to use throughout the app. The requirement is that when the entry has no text, the label above should be hidden and vice versa. I tried creating a content view but am unable to set the visibility while using the custom control from an xaml.

CustomControl

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace iTrans.CustomControls
{
    public partial class LabelEditor : ContentView
    {
        public LabelEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text))
                label.IsVisible = false;
            else
                label.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="iTrans.CustomControls.LabelEditor">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Label x:Name="label"></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="entry" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged"/>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Usage:

```
<custom:LabelEditor EditorText="hello" LabelText="bye"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some bindable properties to your custom view, one for editor text and one for label text.

[This blog post](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/) will show you how to do that.